# jQuery Clock Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery clock code from [this site](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/css3-digital-clock-with-jquery/) and everything works great except I need the clock to always show Eastern Standard Time (GMT-5). How do I edit this code to reflect that?

**jQuery Script:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
// Create two variable with the names of the months and days in an array
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]; 
var dayNames= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]

// Create a newDate() object
var newDate = new Date();
// Extract the current date from Date object
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
// Output the day, date, month and year    
$('#Date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + " " + newDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());

setInterval( function() {
    // Create a newDate() object and extract the seconds of the current time on the visitor's
    var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
    // Add a leading zero to seconds value
    $("#sec").html(( seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + seconds);
    },1000);

setInterval( function() {
    // Create a newDate() object and extract the minutes of the current time on the visitor's
    var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    // Add a leading zero to the minutes value
    $("#min").html(( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes);
    },1000);

setInterval( function() {
    // Create a newDate() object and extract the hours of the current time on the visitor's
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    // Add a leading zero to the hours value
    $("#hours").html(( hours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + hours);
    }, 1000);

});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="clock">
<div id="Date"></div>

<ul class="clock-ul">
    <li class="clock-li" id="hours"> </li>
    <li class="clock-li" id="point">:</li>
    <li class="clock-li" id="min"> </li>
    <li class="clock-li" id="point">:</li>
    <li class="clock-li" id="sec"> </li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about HTML&JQUERY not EE

Comment: I think this is essentially a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s) also lists a few possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to receive the answer from Rainer Jeschor of Experts-Exchange. You can view the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EE_RainerJ/umcka2th/

```
setInterval( function() {
// Define the tomezones offset
var timezoneOffset = -5;
// Get the local date from client
var currentDate = new Date();
// Get UTC time
utcDate = currentDate.getTime() + (currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
// Set to UTC - 5
estDate = new Date(utcDate + (3600000*timezoneOffset));
var seconds = estDate.getSeconds();
var minutes = estDate.getMinutes();
var hours = estDate.getHours();

// Add a leading zero to seconds value
$("#sec").html(( seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + seconds);
// Add a leading zero to the minutes value
$("#min").html(( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes);
// Add a leading zero to the hours value
$("#hours").html(( hours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + hours);
},1000);
```