# Javascript New Date Changing Hour Value

Tags: javascript

I am receiving times in the an AJAX request and am converting them using the `new Date()` function.

I receive `2013-06-18T12:00:15Z`

However, somehow I get the following after `new Date()`:

```
Tue Jun 18 2013 08:00:15 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Why is it not:

```
Tue Jun 18 2013 12:00
```

See the following demo:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_convert

Comment: those should be equivalent.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, they are, but I need it to be Tue Jun 18 2013 12

Comment: that is just a formatting issue. you need to format it appropriately.

Comment: The linked demo does not match the question.  Did you edit a w3schools try it?  Use jsfiddle.net instead, that saves your changes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a time zone problem. You must be in the EDT timezone (GMT-0400). To correctly parse the date you should tell the parser in which timezone your date is correct.

For you parse your date like this : 
`new Date('2013-06-18 12:00:15 GMT-0400')`

"GMT-0400" means GMT time minus 4 hours

Or if you don't wish to reformat your string, you can use the `date.getUTC*` functions to get the time as you parsed it.

The full list is available at [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Vaim Caen's answer that this is a timezone issue, but not with parsing - the date is being parsed fine, *but* into your local timezone, while you're expecting it to be parsed into UTC date.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048201/2181514) shows how to convert from your current timezone to UTC - applying this to the [TryIt](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_convert) demo gives:

```
var msec = Date.parse("2013-06-18T12:00:15Z");
// or: var msec = Date.parse("Tue Jun 18 2013 08:00:15 GMT-0400 (EDT)");
var d = new Date(msec);
d.setTime( d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
```

**Edit:** If you all you're interested in is displaying the date (no further manipulations) then you can use:

```
d.toUTCString()
```

which will show the date in GMT (for me it actually shows "GMT" so most likely not of use!)

The alternative is to add a function to the prototype to show the date in whatever format you want and use the `date.getUTC*` methods.

Comment: The date is being parsed as a GMT date.  This is the normal behaviour with the "dateTtimeZ"  format.  But it is displayed in the local time zone format.

Comment: Interesting - how do you determine this?  If this was the case commands like `.getHours()` would give the UTC hours, not local timezone.  Given that the `.toUTCx()` methods were *added* in JavaScript 1.3, I would conclude that it parses/stores it with local timezone, not UTC (or GMT).  TBH however it stores it internally is irrelevant if all the commands give the timezone version.

Comment: In the parse() [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) it is stated that :  _The UTC time zone is used to interpret arguments in ISO 8601 format that do not contain time zone information_ (and GMT and UTC are the same)

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted your comment - to reword/summarise: When no timezone is present on the input, it is parsed *as* GMT, *into* your local timezone.