# Javascript setting date not working, showing wrong hour

Tags: javascript, date, setting

I want to set date and time to `2016-05-11T00:00:00.000Z`

```
var date = new Date(2016,4,12,0,0,0,0);
```

but instead of showing Date `2016-05-11T00:00:00.000Z` its giving Date `2016-05-11T19:00:00.000Z`

I want time 00:00:00 but its giving 19:00:00

Comment: It might be your time zone, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s

Comment: showing where? How? Your code just creates a date object. It doesn't *"show"* it anywhere. Are you outputting it? If so how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specifed arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use new Date([Date.UTC(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)) with the same arguments. [[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)]