# How to convert UTC timezone to getTimezoneoffset()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

Here is the UTC date/time: `2014-06-01 12:00`

how can i convert the above date and time to a new timezone with this:

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset();` or even this:

`-(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60);`

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:CSS]?

Comment: Duplicate -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s