# Format Date in AngularJS coming from $http.get in large json data response

Tags: angularjs, json

I am successfully calling $http.get in my Angular controller and getting back a large json object. Like this:

```
var self=this;
self.createNewStatusReport = function()
{
    $http.get(self.NewStatusReportUrl).then(function(response)
    {
        self.AngularModel.StatusReportJsons.push(response.data);
    });
};
```

The returned json includes many dates. The format, unfortunately, looks like this: /Date(1420099200000)/. Here's a simplified piece of the response data:

```
{
    "StatusReportID": 25, 
    "DueDate": "/Date(1468566000000)/", 
    "SubmitDate": null,
    "WorkStatement": [
    {
        "WorkStatementID": 41, 
        "Milestone": [
        {
            "MilestoneID": 501,
            "ContractorComments": null, 
            "Title": "Do some specific piece of work", 
            "StartDate": "/Date(1459494000000)/", 
            "EndDate": "/Date(1469948400000)/", 
            "IsCompleted": false, 
            ...
```

I also have (some) control over the server side, but can't change the date types in StatusReportJson from DateTime? to string. It is MVC written in C#:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult NewStatusReport(string agreementNumber)
{
    var statusReport = StatusReports.GetStatusReport(25);
    return Json(new StatusReportJson(statusReport), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Is there an easy way to recursively convert these date strings to date objects? The response data comes to me already parsed; can I insert my own parse step? On the server side, can I make the dates come in as date strings that look more like "2016-04-01T00:00:00" or simply "2016-04-01" without modifying my StatusReportJson object's data types? Others have already solved the conversion problem here: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-microsoft-json-date) I need help structuring where to put the solution so it is effective in my case. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Simple to  loop over data and convert each instance before pushing to array. Having to do client side data transformations is not uncommon

Comment: That creates a dependency I would rather not have. If the StatusReportJson changes on the server side, which it is likely to do, I don't want to have to change the client side to match. Makes for less maintainable code.

Comment: I have no idea how you can change things at server-side. But at client-side, you could just use a filter that transforms the /Date()/ string into a number, and then passes that number to the standard date filter.

Comment: *"Makes for less maintainable code"* ... doesn't make sense.

Comment: Interesting idea. Are you talking about an Angular filter? (I'm not very familiar with them yet.) Assuming I could look up how to write one, how would I put it in place to work here, before the json is parsed?

Comment: If use an angular filter would only need it in view `{{milestone.StartDate | dateParsefilter}}`. If need date objects such as for datepickers then do a transform of your data first when you receive it

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I get an object. The string has already been deserialized by the time I get it. Plus, I need real date objects, not simply to display bad dates nicely to the user. I'm doing more with the dates than just displaying them.

Comment: So iterate through that object and do a transform of the values for all the date related fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this. First, I used the JavaScript serializer on the server side like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult NewStatusReport(string agreementNumber)
{
    var statusReport = StatusReports.GetStatusReport(25);
    var statusReportJson = new StatusReportJson(statusReport);
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(statusReportJson);
    return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, on the client side, I pulled in code from this excellent page http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html and called it like this:

```
var self = this;
$http.get(self.NewStatusReportUrl).then(function(response)
{
    var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response.data, true);
    self.AngularModel.StatusReportJsons.push(jsonObject);
});
```

Thanks to Robert Koritnik for the answer! And thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves your problem:

```
$scope.DateIssue = function(input) {
input = '/Date(1468566000000)/';
$scope.formatedDate = input.toString().replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', '');
$scope.formatedDate = $filter('date', $scope.formatedDate);
return $scope.formatedDate
```

};

Comment: Thanks for this. Hmmm. But I have an object, not a string. Is there a way to run a function which pre-processes the response before angular does its json deserialization?

Comment: you can convert that object as string and use this function.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I thought helpful.
Most of the suggestions were to locally convert it. In my case the date is returned as string (with Timezone info).

E.g. '2018-06-01T13:57:41.3867449Z'

So I created a common service for getJson & PostJson and in handled responses there with '$q'.

```
if (response.data) {
    // Check for datetime object & convert  
    // TODO:: *** May impact performance, so check later or use momentJS
    //console.info('Before-convertDateStringsToDates:', new Date());
    appUtils.convertDateStringsToDates(response.data);
    //console.info('After-convertDateStringsToDates:', new Date());
}
```

My appUtil method is as below:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Ref: http://aboutcode.net/2013/07/27/json-date-parsing-angularjs.html
// Function to convert string (as ReGex format) property to date - used as generic in Common Serivce.
convertDateStringsToDates(input) {
    // ReGex for format we receive from Web API e.g. "1980-05-09T00:00:00Z"
    var jsonDateTimeFormatRegex = "((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))";
    // Ignore things that aren't objects.
    if (typeof input !== "object") return input;

    for (var key in input) {
        if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        var value = input[key];
        var match;
        // Check for string properties which look like dates.
        // TODO: Improve this regex to better match ISO 8601 date strings.
        if (typeof value === "string" && (match = value.match(jsonDateTimeFormatRegex))) {
            // Assume that Date.parse can parse ISO 8601 strings, or has been shimmed in older browsers to do so.
            //console.info(match[0]);
            var date = new Date(match[0]); // Need to convert to UTC. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14006555/1161069
            input[key] = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()));

            // var milliseconds = Date.parse(match[0]);
            // if (!isNaN(milliseconds)) {
            //     input[key] = new Date(milliseconds);
            // }
        } else if (typeof value === "object") {
            // Recurse into object
            this.convertDateStringsToDates(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, after each GET or POST request, I get my JSON with proper dates.

Just in case someone wants to know Web API code, it's as below:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    //var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // other code ......

    var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
    //jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    JsonSerializerSettings jSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.None
    };
    jSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jSettings;

    // rest of the code....
}
```