# How do I construct a UTC date in Javascript as an object, not a number?

Tags: javascript, date

In Javascript, given `d=new Date()` it might be the case that `d.getHours()!=d.getUtcHours()`.

I can construct a `Date` object, giving the components explicitly

```
new Date (y, m, d, hrs, mins)
```

but if these components are UTC then I have a problem. From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

> The UTC() method differs from the Date constructor in two ways.
>
> - Date.UTC() uses universal time instead of the local time.
> - Date.UTC() **returns a time value as a number** instead of creating a Date object.

How do I construct a `Date` *object* given UTC components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439871/2048417) you can do it like this:

`new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))`

Answer (score 1):

How about `new Date(Date.UTC(...))`, e.g. `new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 9, 5, 13, 11, 5))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var milliseconds = Date.UTC(y, m, d, hrs, mins);
var date = new Date(milliseconds);
```