# Full Calendar Dates are different in different countries

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using fullcalendar.js and i am having problem with the timezone. 
It is working perfectly well from where i am living but my client who lives in Canada Burlington doesn't get the same date he clicks on. i have set the zone to -05:00(their zone) but doesn't help, is there a way to set the timezone to local? 
so no matter where you access the full calendar it show.

[image]

These dates that are highlited are shown as 6 in Canada, on the same date clicked.

this is the code i'm using to open the modal on dayclick

```
   dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    var click = date._d;
    var month = new Array();
    month[0] = "January";
    month[1] = "February";
    month[2] = "March";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "June";
    month[6] = "July";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "October";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "December";
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    $("#myModal").modal("show");

    document.getElementById("date").setAttribute("value", click.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (click.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0" + click.getDate()).slice(-2));

    document.getElementById("month").setAttribute("value", month[click.getMonth()]);
    document.getElementById("str_day").setAttribute("value", ("0" + click.getDate()).slice(-2));
    document.getElementById("end_day").setAttribute("value", weekday[click.getDay()]);
  },
  eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    console.log(event);
    var title = event.title;
    var end = event.end.format();
    var start = event.start.format();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'fullcalender/process.php',
      data: 'type=resetdate&title='+title+'&start='+start+'&end='+end+'&eventid='+event.id,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        if(response.status != 'success')
          revertFunc();
      },
      error: function(e){
        revertFunc();
        alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
      }
    });
```

And this is the code used to add in the database

```
if($type == 'new')
{
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'].'+'.$_POST['zone'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO calendar(`title`, `startdate`, `enddate`, `allDay`) VALUES('$title','$startdate','$startdate','false')");
    $lastid = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success','eventid'=>$lastid));
}
```

Comment: Check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/439871/2159528) to set a date based on UTC time... If it doesn't fix your problem, you'll have to show some code.

Comment: i've added the code now :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as storing your times, they should be stored as UTC timestamp. For retrieving the timezone I use [jstz](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) to get the users timezone, its as simple as these two lines.

```
var tz = jstz.determine();
var timezone = tz.name();
```

This will give you a timezone like "America/Chicago" for wherever the user is, this is great because you dont have to ask the user for their timezone and it will work anywhere. Then pass your [timezone](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/) along with your request for events and you can use your server side language for converting from UTC to the supplied timezone when retrieving events.

```
events: {
    url: "calendarManager.php?request=get&timezone=" + timezone + "&userid=" + userID
},
```

You should also use

```
timezone: "local",
```

in your calendar configuration and then convert from UTC to the users local timezone when returning events using the method above.

Comment: i have been trying to find this line in fullcalendar.js but am unable to find this :/

Comment: what line do you mean? The configuration will not be set in fullcalendar.js, you will set it as a configuration option when initialising the calendar.

Comment: oh Thanks :)
though i have made a temporary solution as the client could see the previous date he clicked on, so i added 1 in the date, but i know that is not the permanent way to do it so wanted to make it permanent :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem after 3 days, 
The problem was I was using getDate(),
using getUTCDat() fixed the problem :)