# How to convert date string by timezone name?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

For example, if there is a date string, regardless of whether it has a time zone:`2019-10-12T05:24:24.872043Z`, how can I convert it into a date object for the corresponding time zone by using the time zone name `Asia/Shanghai`。

Using only JavaScript and not relying on third-party libraries, I know that moment-timezone seems to solve this problem.

The following code can only get a string and cannot be converted to a date object in a given timezone:

```
var asiaTime = new Date('2019-10-09T08:26:24.289528Z').toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: "Asia/Shanghai"});
```

I expect to get a date object for a given timezone.

Comment: Date objects don't have a timezone, they're just a time value that is an offset from the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z), hence are UTC. They use host settings to deduce the local date and time. The *getTimezoneOffset* method returns the host system offset for the date and time represented by the Date's time value.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Javascript set timezone in date object itself like setTimeOffset()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623363/javascript-set-timezone-in-date-object-itself-like-settimeoffset).