# Why does JavaScript add 5 hours to my date?

Tags: javascript

I have a datetime string and want to create a JS Date Object:

```
var dt_string = "2/10/2018 11:52:41 PM";
var d_object = new Date(dt_string);
```

I want to print the date/time in a different format (which just so happens to match the ISO String):

```
console.log("date/time: " + d_object.toISOString().substring(0,10) + " " + d_object.toISOString().substring(11,19));
```

I expect to see:

```
"2018-02-10 23:52:41"
```

Instead I get this:

```
"2018-02-11 04:52:41"
```

Which is 5 hours later than it's supposed to be. After debugging, I found this:

```
new Date(d_string): Sat Feb 10 2018 23:52:41 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Which makes me think it's adding 5 hours to my time to match GMT. How do I get JS to respect my original time, and not change it?

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. JavaScript's `new Date` parses the date assuming it's local, but `toISOString` returns it in ISO8601 format, which is in UTC/"Zulu" (hence the trailing `Z`). Frankly you're lucky it was that close, the date you're providing is *clearly* in October, not February, 2018!

Comment: `toISOString()` outputs UTC date - if you didn't chop bits out of it, you'd see that

Comment: I updated my answer to actually provide a simple solution to your question and explain the behaviour you observed. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should make your life simple and install [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

However, as comments have suggested, `toISOString` uses the UTC form.

If you really care about printing in your timezone, [check out this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s).

Here is a manipulation of one of those answers to print what you wanted. Definitely not the ideal method.

```js
var dt_string = "2/10/2018 11:52:41 PM";
var d_object = new Date(dt_string);
console.log(d_object);

d_object.setTime(d_object.getTime() - d_object.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
console.log(d_object);
```

Comment: This solution lead me to the my answer. For my situation I need to add the timezone, as in:   d_object.setTime(d_object.getTime() + d_object.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
console.log(d_object);

Answer (score 0):

It is assumed that every `Date` object's timezone is the local machine's timezone: **UTC-05** in your case.

As `toISOString()` returns a **zero UTC offset** date (in the form of a string) then you get **5 hours** added.

Note that the `Date` object doesn't store internally any timezone information.

In order to answer your question:

> How do I get JS to respect my original time, and not change it?

If your "original time" is meant to be **zero UTC offset** then you can specify that in the string passed to `Date` constructor:

```
var dt_string = "2/10/2018 11:52:41 PM UTC+0000";
//                                     ^^^^^^^^
var d_object = new Date(dt_string);
```

Now if you evaluate:

```
console.log("date/time: " + d_object.toISOString().substring(0,10) + " " + d_object.toISOString().substring(11,19));
```

You get:

```
"date/time: 2018-02-10 23:52:41"
```

Note that according to what previously written if you inspect `d_object` you'll get the parsed date converted to your local timezone.