# Javascript .getTime() to another timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

So currently my javascript in receiving timestamps like this:

```
tmpTimestamp = new Date(el.timestamp)
tmpTimestamp = tmpTimestamp.getTime()
```

And it it returning the date in milliseconds from epoch in UTC, but since I live in California I need this in GMT-7. I have tried:

```
tmpTimestamp = tmpTimestamp.getTime()-(tmpTimestamp.getTimezoneOffset()*60000)
```

But this does not seem to work, any help?

Comment: moment would be a good option.

Comment: Timezone support in base Javascript is very limited. Have a look at https://momentjs.com/

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s

Comment: I just got moment, how would I convert this to the right timezone?

Comment: @WesleyWeisenberger https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Comment: Since you have tagged highcharts, if this is indeed for highcharts, you can use: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezone or https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezoneOffset