# NodeJS timezone inconsistent behaviour

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, utc

I'm trying to parse fully specified date ISO string and then print the corresponding date object. My laptop is in `Europe/Berlin` timezone (i.e `UTC+02` at summer time). However when I explicitly set `TZ=UTC+02` env variable for the node process, the script below produces unexpected results:

```
// test.js
const t = '2018-07-03T10:00:00.000+02:00';
console.log(t, new Date(t), new Date(t).toLocaleString());

$ TZ='UTC+02' node test.js
> 2018-07-03T10:00:00.000+02:00 2018-07-03T08:00:00.000Z 2018-7-3 06:00:00 // 6 AM!!!
```

Then I checked for the timezone offset (which must be opposite to UTC offset in accordance with the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)) and it gives me positive `+02:00` value for `TZ=Europe/Berlin` timezone and negative for the `TZ=UTC+02`.

```
const x = new Date();
const offset= -x.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log((offset>=0?"+":"")+parseInt(offset/60)+":"+offset%60);
```

How can one explain such behaviour?

```
$ node --version  # on OS X high sierra 10.13.4 
> v8.7.0
```

Comment: Hey I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s

Comment: @t3__rry it doesn't explain the difference of offsets for `Europe/Berlin` and `UTC+02`.