# Kendo LocalTime Popup Edit

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a Kendo Grid with Ajax binding implemented in my application created in MVC5. I need to be able to show and edit local date and time that is saved in my db in UTC. I have a template form for Edit. I know how to show local time in the Grid using JavaScript onDataBound event. However, when I try to display that same data in the pop up form it is displayed in UTC format that it pulls from the db. How do I make it consistent and show date and time in local format on the Grid and in the pop up Edit form?

Thank you,
Anna.

Comment: You need to change the timezone of a date in js, that right ? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16048201/1267304) out.

Comment: I do, however, it needs to work with Kendo Grid that has Ajax binding so unfortunately the above link will not work for me.

Comment: Does `kendo.toString(date, 'g')` works for you? It should fix the timezone.

Comment: I think this related with your situation https://www.telerik.com/forums/utc-datetime-handling-with-datepicker-and-kendo-ui-grid-edit-dialog