# How can I setLocaleHours() on a date object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone

When I execute

```
myDate = new Date('2000-02-02 12:30:00')
```

I get a date object like this `2000-02-02T11:30:00.000Z` because there is a difference of one hour between my timezone (Europe/Vienna) and UTC.

I can now change the hour by doing

```
myDate.setHours(10)
```

and the result will be a date object like this `2000-02-02T09:30:00.000Z` because of the one hour difference.

I can also set the UTC hours by

```
myDate.setUTCHours(10)
```

to get a dateobject like this `2000-02-02T10:30:00.000Z`

---

I'm looking for something similar to

```
myDate.setLocaleHours(10, "America/New_York")
```

(which doesn't exist)

What is the best way to set the hours to a specific value in a timezone which is not my current one and also not UTC?

Comment: moment.js timezone plugin would be a help here

Comment: Thanks, I have heard of it but it's my last resort because I would like to have a solution without dependencies.

Comment: Then perhaps you are better off looking for an API source that can give you the current offset for a specific timezone to use in `setHours`. Issues like daylight savings time make it complex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Date with a set timezone without using a string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation)

Comment: "2000-02-02 12:30:00" is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so paring is implementation dependent. It results in an invalid Date in at least one current browser. You might consider the *timeZone* option of [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I setLocaleHours() on a date object?
>
> What is the best way to set the hours to a specific value in a timezone which is not my current one and also not UTC?

You can't.  At least, not on the `Date` object.  It has no ability to *set* time based on an arbitrary time zone.

There is work in progress to rectify this, by adding a new set of standard objects to ECMAScript.  See the [TC39 Temporal proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) for more details.  The temporal `ZonedInstant` will have functionality to work with named time zones.

However, for now, you will need a library that understands time zones.  [Moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) is one option, though, these days the Moment team recommends [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) for modern app development.  Another great option is [js-Joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/).

Comment: It's slightly awkward in Luxon because the setters always use the DateTime's zone, so you need something like `dt.setZone("America/New_York").set({ hours: 10 }).setZone("local")`