# javascript datetime in custom format as per timezone

Tags: javascript, date

I want datetime in custom format as per below.

```
2019-01-24T05:52:29:420 +0000 GMT+0000
```

but when I try do it using below syntax I did not work.

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
alert(currentdate);
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: This may help you? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation/439871#439871

Comment: "*How to format a date*" has been asked many, many times before.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Moment.js, you can format JS dates with this quite easily.

e.g:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // January 24th 2019, 5:13:29 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Thursday
```

in your case:

```
moment(currentdate).format('the format you would like');
```

https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I want output in plain javascript.

Comment: You don't want to use any libraries? and why?

Comment: I dont want to use any library.I am working in angular application

Answer (score -1):

**its very simple you just have to do currentdate.toISOString() which will return "2019-01-24T06:19:19.975Z", now its simple just remove last char from string and concat the other string part in it.**

```
var currentdate = new Date().toISOString();

alert(currentdate.substr(0, currentdate.length-1)+' +0000 GMT+0000');
```

Comment: This above is the correct answer.