# DST problems with Google Apps Script and Google calendar

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, dst

I am creating a school project for managing classes, I have a problem with time zones and DST here is my code:

```
javascript
dejt = new Date(thisYear, 8, day, beginTime, endTime, 0, 0);
dejt.toLocaleString("en-US", {timezone: "Europe/Belgrade"});
```

And I pass I through some functions until:

```
javascript
function makeCalendar(name, begin, end, calendar) {
    var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar).createEventSeries(
        name,
        begin,
        end,
        CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
            .addWeeklyRule().interval(2).until(endDate)
    );
}
```

This works well until it hits October 29th after that everything is moved one hour earlier.

> How do I manage DST?

EDIT:

After setting script to GMT (No daylight saving) things got more consistent and every date vas +00:00

```
Logs:
[19-02-12 11:30:15:809 CET] Sun Feb 17 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2019
[19-02-12 11:30:15:810 CET] Mon Feb 18 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2019
[19-02-12 11:30:24:051 CET] Mon Sep 03 14:00:00 GMT+00:00 2018
[19-02-12 11:30:24:503 CET] Mon Sep 03 14:50:00 GMT+00:00 2018
```

Now only problem is that recurring events just change time when daylight savings should be (Not a new bug, it was like this before).

EDIT:

New stuff I found out:
If you edit events manually there is time zone box; My script makes it UTC but i can manually edit or remove it. Problem here is that I need to do it manually.

I also found .setTimeZone(string) in Google documentation:
[here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-recurrence#setTimeZone(String)), and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#settimezonetimezone)

The problem now is that i cannot make it work, no matter what i tried events would and up as UTC

Comment: Could you share how exactly you pass your begin and end dates into `makeCalendar`? In my case with `var beginDate = new Date(thisYear, 8, day, beginTime, 0, 0, 0);   var endDate = new Date(thisYear, 8, day, endTime, 0, 0, 0);` it was fine and there was no issue with DST

Comment: There is a lot of passing, but I can provide the whole code if you are interested

Comment: Yes, that could be helpful, I think

Comment: I edited post with code

Comment: thanks! actually, yeah, the thing was about my script's time zone, not about the full code of yours (probably you can remove it from the post). Looks like I came up with a solution, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some digging into this, looks like there's something like a solution.

Google Calendar will look at script's timezone unless it is specified in the `Date` object you're passing into it. In your case it is not (`toLocaleString` will not modify the original object, and if it would, you'd run into errors with passing strings into `createEventSeries`). Anyway, your script's timezone seems to be Belgrade, and there's DST, time changes, etc.

Finally, possible solution. I don't know if Calendar service allows not to take DST in consideration so trying to get round the issue:

```
// function to convert date to UTC so that it retains original hours value
function convertDateToUTC(date, timezoneOffset) { 
    return new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate(), date.getUTCHours() + timezoneOffset, date.getUTCMinutes(), date.getUTCSeconds()); 
}
// 1 is the timezone offset from GMT
makeCalendar('test event', convertDateToUTC(beginDate, 1), convertDateToUTC(endDate, 1), calendar.getId());
```

Function `convertDateToUTC` is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14006555/3555636).

Using this, I got (begin time was 7 am originally):

[image: calendar screenshot]

Comment: It still does not work    Logs:                                                                                 
[19-02-12 11:26:57:824 CET] Sun Feb 17 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019
[19-02-12 11:26:57:825 CET] Mon Feb 18 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019
[19-02-12 11:27:05:309 CET] Mon Sep 03 16:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018
[19-02-12 11:27:05:743 CET] Mon Sep 03 16:50:00 GMT+02:00 2018

Comment: Is it still the old way: before 29th of October time is correct, after — one hour earlier?
The dates in the logs, how are they different from the ones you expect?

Comment: It's same problem but now every date has same offset, before this dates had different offsets no matter what I did and this is important for different part of the code that handled breaks