# Javascript How to convert a timezone into the actual timezone abbreviation?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a date and need to convert it into this format
02/27/2020 3:00PM (MST)

What is the fastest way to do that in javscript like a one liner?

I tried

```
  var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute:'numeric', timeZoneName: 'short' };        
      this.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
```

This also does not work

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone, options);
```

as I am getting asia/caluctta invalid language tag

While this works for UnitedStates this does not work for users in russia, india, europe, china.

It will show the date as

```
02/28/2020 +500 GMT
```

I need it to show as

**02/28/2020 (IST)** for India

or

**02/28/2020 (JST)** for Japan Standard time

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation/ help?

Comment: Is it required to convert MST to IST every time? What does your input data look like?

Comment: input data is all dynamic. I used MST as an example since I am in mountain standard time. However it could be any timezone but I just need it in the format for that person's timezone

Comment: Is your question mostly boils down to *how to convert timezone offset into timezone abbreviation*?

Comment: Yes I have updated the title to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to try **[Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)**. It's a javascript library made especially for easier manipulation with time. Just download the .js and add it to your index.html before your script.