# How to get the date of last day of week with a specific timezone using js

Tags: javascript, timezone

I want to get date of the last day of week with a specific timezone.

I got this code that works good but it shows the computer timezone. i want to add a specific timezone like GMT-0500

```
 {     
 var lastday = date.getDate() - (date.getDay() - 1) + 6;
 return new Date(date.setDate(lastday)); 
 }
dt = new Date(); 
dt.setHours(23,59,59,999);
document.getElementById("lastday").innerHTML = endOfWeek(dt).toString();
console.log(endOfWeek(dt).toString());
```

How can i change the timezone? please help.

Comment: @InsightCoders - Please clarify what you mean exactly by "last day of week".  Do you mean Saturday or Sunday in all cases? Or do you expect the week start/end days to be determined by locale?

Comment: @mplungjan - If I'm reading the OP correctly, they're not asking how to set a specific time zone, but how to get the last day of a week based on the current time in a specific time zone.  Those are two related, but still different things.

Comment: Heel read has code to set the last day of the week. Apply time zone first then do the thing already posted

Comment: @mplungjan - nope.  The `Date` object can't do that.  It can only manipulate time with regard to UTC or local time.  See my answer below.  Thanks.

Comment: So how come you answer with [code identical to the dupe I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54453990/295783) ?

Comment: @mplungjan - dups are about the question, not the answers.  But I suppose until the OP responds with more details about the "last day of the week" part, there's no point in answering. I deleted my answer until then.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I mark as dupe a question that has an answer in another question. If the main issue is X I don’t care that the title is not exact the same. This question is not about last day because that is already answered by OP, but about time zones

Comment: Form the above code i am getting the date of the last day of week(Sunday). the output is Sun Apr 26 2020 23:59:59 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time). i want to change the timezone, so it will be Sun Apr 26 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0500 (US Standard Time).

Comment: did you try moment.js? https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Hi.  Sorry, but the `Date` object cannot do that.  Also there's no such thing as "US Standard Time".  (The US has many time zones).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824