# How to get exact time when converting date into string

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime, datetime-format

i want get current time, when i convert `new Date()` into sting but when it converts reduces `5.30` hours based on my time zone.

[image]

How can i get same time which returns in `new Date()` method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Date with a set timezone without using a string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
```

How ever format you want you may adjust

Comment: it return new format