# Close order depending of working hours using React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I am using React to create online food ordering and I need to disable the ordering when the restaurant is closed, until it opens again.

something like this:

```
  const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("rs-RS");
  const day = new Date().getDay();

  if (day <= 5 && time < "08:00:00" && time > "23:30:00") {
    console.log("closed");
  } else if (day === 6 && time < "09:00:00" && time > "23:30:00") {
    console.log("closed");
  } else if (day === 0 && time < "12:00:00" && time > "20:00:00") {
    console.log("closed");
  } else {
    console.log("open");
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to do time comparisons in JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a Date with a String. I would use [`Date.setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

```js
 const time = new Date();
  const day = new Date().getDay();

  if ((day <= 5) && (time < (new Date().setHours(8)) && (time > (new Date().setHours(23, 30))) {
    console.log("closed");
  } else if ((day === 6) && (time < (new Date().setHours(9)) && (time > (new Date().setHours(23, 30))) {
    console.log("closed");
  } else if ((day === 0) && (time < (new Date().setHours(12)) && (time > (new Date().setHours(20))) {
    console.log("closed");
  } else {
    console.log("open");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks like the time is not correct and the console is not gettting the print right. Must be something with time format.

Comment: i've edited the code. Can you try it again please? @Madizm

Comment: still not working, the format of the hours is incorrect, new Date().setHours(12), when i console log it, it's showing random numbers.

Comment: Does it work now? I've removed the timezone @Madizm You can set if afterwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation