# How to run timer from custom datetime?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

Need to run a timer from custom datetime(past or future). `Ex: Jun 15 2021 15:45:31 GMT+0530", "Tue Jun 15 2021 15:45:32 GMT+0530"` (seconds)

```
startTimer() {
    const dateTime =  new Date('2021-06-15T15:45:30');
    setInterval(() => {
      this.now = dateTime;
      this.startTimer();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

// timer is not working and it is in static. (`Tue Jun 15 2021 15:45:31 GMT+0530`)

component :

```
{{ now }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alter the actual value of `this.now`...

```js
let now = new Date('2021-06-15T15:45:30');

function startTimer() {
  setInterval(() => {
    now = new Date(now.getTime() + 1000);
    console.log(now)
  }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```

Above is a simple vanillaJS version. Since you tagged `momentjs` you might also want to have a look at [add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/).
Alternatively, since you are using angular, you have some nice options to work with timers using rxjs - like [interval](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval) or [timer](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/timer).

Comment: When I reset the time zone in mobile or windows, the time (now) is changed. How set static time zone to halt the change?

Comment: The javascript `Date` has several options to work with timezones... Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set `dateTime` before you start the timer with `setInterval()`
and then after 1 second the time is being set again to the same date.
also you should't be calling `this.startTimer();` from inside the  `setInterval()`.

Try this:

```
const now =  new Date('2021-06-15T15:45:30');

startTimer() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.now.setSeconds(this.now.getSeconds() + 1)
    }, 1000);
}
```