# What type of date string is this? `20210713T015433.354Z`

Tags: date

I'm working with some data where I don't know how the time string was generated but an example of what the date string looks like is this `20210713T015433.354Z`

I've looked at some examples of date strings ([ex1](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/time/convert-string-or-numeric-time-values-into-data-format.htm) and [ex2](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/)) but haven't had any luck decoding it.

I know that the first half of the string is YYYYMMDD, and then I think that T means times but then I don't know what `015433.354Z` is.

My eventual goal is to make this into a `Date` objects in JS but I can't deduce the formatting. beyond the day it occured.

Comment: Z is Zulu timezone - GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format provided is [ISO 8601](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/manpki/pki_iso8601datetime.html). Maybe you want to try the following to get a `Date` object:

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 7, 13, 1, 54, 33, 354))
```

As pointed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439871/6328506) SO answer.