# Need to convert date string to iso time formats

Tags: javascript, react-datepicker

I am using react date picker and getting the selected time value in the below format

Thu Oct 13 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

i need to convert the above string to the below formats

(a) "2022-10-13T00:00:00+05:30"
(b) "2022-11-03T18:30:00.000Z"
(c) "2022-11-03T18:30:00.000Z"

i was able to achieve the format (b) and (c) using the below code

const dateStr = "Thu Oct 13 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530";
console.log(new Date(dateStr).toUTCString());

but was not able to get the conversion for (a).also as per the logic the month is 1 month ahead and the date is 21 days ahead of the actual value  passed.Any way to resolve this?

Comment: You can look at this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation/439871#439871), this can be done as follows. You were almost there `.toLocaleString()` is the method that you want. As the name suggests, alternatively you can use a library like **moment** . `new Date(
  new Date("2021-01-01T00:00:00")
    .toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})
).toISOString();` And this https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-convert-date-string-to-iso-format

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript `Date` object has no function to return the local ISO date format. Here is a function that does that. If the offset is omitted, the browser local time is assumed:

```js
function toLocalISO(date, offset) {
  if(offset == null) {
    offset = date.getTimezoneOffset(); // browser offset in minutes
  }
  return new Date(date.getTime() - (offset * 60000)).toISOString().replace(/Z$/, function() {
    return (offset > 0 ? '-' : '+') +
           ('0' + (Math.abs(offset)/60*100))
            .replace(/^.*(..)(..)$/, '$1:$2')
            .replace(/50$/, '30');
  });
}

const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toISOString() + ' <== ISO');
console.log(toLocalISO(date) + ' <== browser local ISO');
let offset = -330; // India offset in minutes
console.log(toLocalISO(date, offset) + ' <== India local ISO');
```

Output: (for me in California local time)

```
2022-11-04T21:10:40.969Z <== ISO
2022-11-04T14:10:40.969-07:00 <== browser local ISO
2022-11-05T02:40:40.969+05:30 <== India local ISO
```