# Why does the script increase the entered time by 33 minutes?

Tags: javascript

There is a script that, when entering time in column A or B, should substitute the current date for the entered time.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
    if (range.getColumn() === 1 || range.getColumn() === 2) {
    var time = range.getValue();
    if (typeof time === 'object') {
      var hours = time.getHours();
      var minutes = time.getMinutes();
      var date = new Date();
      date.setHours(hours);
      date.setMinutes(minutes);
      date.setSeconds(0); // Обнуляем секунды
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd.M HH:mm');
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()).setValue(formattedDate);    
}  
}
}
```

But, after entering, for example, 14:00 in a cell, the value first changes to 11.25.2023 14:00, and then immediately to 11.25.2023 14:33.
**With what it can be connected?**

When replacing date.setMinutes(minutes); on date.setMinutes(minutes - 33); The cell displays the actual entered time -33 minutes (11.25.2023 13:27).

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/create-a-date-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-string-representation/439871#439871

Comment: What should I see there?
Can you tell me what needs to be replaced?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But, after entering, for example, 14:00 in a cell, the value first changes to 11.25.2023 14:00, and then immediately to 11.25.2023 14:33.`. In your script, when a value is put into column "A" or "B", `onEdit` is run only one time. So I cannot understand your 3rd action. Is your actual script only your showing script? In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue you're facing might be related to the timezone and daylight saving time adjustments. When working with dates and times in Google Apps Script, it's important to consider the timezone to ensure accurate results.

Here's an updated version of your script that explicitly sets the timezone:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getColumn() === 1 || range.getColumn() === 2) {
    var time = range.getValue();
    if (typeof time === 'object') {
      var hours = time.getHours();
      var minutes = time.getMinutes();
      
      // Create a new Date object with the current date and the entered time
      var date = new Date();
      date.setHours(hours);
      date.setMinutes(minutes);
      date.setSeconds(0); // Reset seconds

      // Explicitly set the timezone to your desired timezone
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT+3', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
      
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn()).setValue(formattedDate);
    }  
  }
}
```

In this example, I set the timezone to `'GMT+3'`, but you should replace it with your actual timezone. You can find the correct timezone identifier for your location from the IANA Time Zone Database.

Please note that the behavior you observed with `date.setMinutes(minutes - 33)` might be a temporary workaround, but it doesn't address the underlying issue related to timezones and daylight saving time changes. It's recommended to use the proper timezone handling in your script.

Comment: The result is the same. And replacing 'GMT+3' with 'Europe/Moscow' does not give anything.